# Session_id changes after 'redirect'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session-cookies

I want to use the session cookie '_app_session' to use the 'session_id' like this:

```
session_id = Rack::Session::Cookie::Base64::Marshal.new.decode(cookies['_app_session'])['session_id']
```

If I refresh the page I always get the same session ID, which is what I expected (since it is stored at the user level). Then if I try to redirect in my controller action

```
redirect_to :back
```

The session id changes. I can navigate to other pages and the session id does not change, so what is this strange behavior? Is this expected?